How can I visualize the movement of a solar sail?
I am a physics teacher in an elementary school. Together with a student we started to investigate the motion of a solar sail. It shall be of 81 m² in size and 16 kg in mass around the sun at a distance of 1 AU with a certain initial velocity. We would like to see a visualization of this sail (to see the real movement of the sail). If possible, one can change the parameters of the initial velocity and the area of the sail to see how the trajectory of this ship will change. Can anyone help us with this?

Kerbal Space Program is a game, but an excellent introduction to orbital mechanics. I think if you tweak the "solar pressure" settings you may get what you are after.

I feel like it might be a possible to get a "spherical-cow"-type solution (perfect reflectivity, etc etc etc) starting from the basic information in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail#Physical_principles_for_reflective_sails ?

Can you say how the size of your sail or the distance from the sun could matter, please?
Won't initial velocity and mass matter more?

Kerbal Space Program
@Woody suggests to use Kerbal Space Program which is a decent spaceflight simulator in the form of an educational and fun video game which costs some money.
Here's a Scott Manley video where he uses it rather quickly to explain trajectories of the Apollo 10 mission including the lunar module which ended up on a heliocentric orbit. You can skim through the video to see if it looks like the kind of program you need. You have to spend a little time learning how to use it but there are tutorials everywhere.  See also

What can the KSP game actually teach about spaceflight and orbital mechanics, and what are its limitations?

where seven passionate answers illustrate how educational so many people feel it can be. Besides, the green alien Kerbals themselves may make the simulation more eye-candy-ish for your audience :-)
HOWEVER, I can't vouch for the quantitative accuracy, so if you want to set up a specific, realistic solar sail simulation in Kerbal Space Program, once you get started feel free to ask an additional question here with your initial results.
Universe Sandbox 2
Universe Sandbox 2 is another software platform you can look into. It also costs some money. Here are some videos showing Manley's use in videos:

Universe Sandbox - Binary, Trinary, Quartenary Star Systems
"The Goblin" and an Exomoon The Size Of Neptune - Universe Sandbox
Universe Sandbox 2 (Alpha) - Simulate The Universe For Fun!

found here.
Python
Python is free and also educational, but you would have to learn it and some math to do the simulations yourself - orbital dynamics in Python is probably not appropriate for 99% of primary school students. Still, it's free and if you learn to use it, it's a skill that stays with you and can be used over and over. I recommend the Anaconda distribution; the registration via email is completely optional.
Feel free to ask a separate new question specifically about simulating a solar sails with Python and plotting their trajectories!

if someone knows of another simulator appropriate for solar sails, please feel free to add a new answer!

Solar sail simulator: KSP. There are multiple mods that add physically-realistic solar sails, complete with deployment and realistic size/mass/everything. A copy of KSP plus CKAN makes installation of those mods a one-step process.

@controlgroup great! I think a newcomer to the world of KSP (like myself and probably the OP) will benefit from a little more clarification; what are mods, where can they be found, and what's CKAN? Thanks!

@controlgroup ah, I see you've now posted a new and sizable answer!

I hope it's ok. A lot of images, since it's a mini KSP tutorial to get a solar ship into orbit.

About CKAN
This is an addendum to @uhoh's answer: Kerbal Space Program has a really good modding API, and there are free mods that add fully-realistic fully-functional solar sails.
The Comprehensive Kerbal Archive Network (CKAN) is a tool that modders use to manage everything; you install it along with KSP, and it does all the mod installation/dependency management/recommended other mods for you.
Here's what it looks like:


You start by picking a game instance in the first menu - it points out the directory, game (since KSP2 is also usable with CKAN), and path of the game files. I remember during setup it was able to find my game files automatically, so don't worry about that.
Then, once you get to the actual info screen for your instance, you can add mods. To add one (for example, Photon Sailor, which adds awesome solar sails that I'll demo in a second), you checkmark the leftmost box next to it, and then click "Apply Changes". It'll take a second to download the mod and get it stuck into the GameData folder (technical detail about KSP you will never have to hear about again), and then it might also ask you to install dependencies or if you want to install related mods. I usually choose not to since they're often QoL mods that I don't notice, and they take up hard drive space, but once you're back at the mod screen, you're good to go.
Then hit "Launch Game", which starts up KSP with all the added mods.
While loading the game, depending on the mods you have installed, you might see a lot of this-

-but that's normal. I've never had a single issue where a mod actually broke my game except because I really wanted it installed but it wasn't good for my game version. Click through "Close" and "Ignore" and whatever, and eventually you'll get to the actual game. (KSP often takes a long time to load; it's around a minute at most for the base game plus a few mods, for me it's several minutes because I have a ton of graphics and expansion mods installed like Waterfall.)
Brief KSP tutorial
Once the game loads, if you want to visualize a solar sail moving around, just make a new file. Click "Start Game" and then "New Game" (don't worry, there are multiple savefiles, "New Game" doesn't delete your progress).
It should look like this:

I'd use Sandbox mode so you don't have to actually play the game to get to the solar sail demo. Once the game loads, you get to your Kerbal Space Center. I'll show how to build a simple little solar sail probe; first, go into the VAB which is the big middle building,

and then you'll be able to assemble a vehicle.
In sandbox you have all the parts already, so start with a probe core (search "Probe Core" and find the RC-L01.

Clicking on it will bring it into the VAB automatically as a first part. Then, search "sail"; this'll bring up mostly solar sails (plus maybe an engine named "Mainsail"). These all have mostly-realistic properties.
To add one, click on it to get it into your hand, and then move it so it sits on top of the probe core. It should snap into place, like so:


These particular probe cores have very little battery, so I would recommend searching "battery" and dragging one of the bigger ones onto the bottom to add as well.

Then, hit the green launch button (looks like a rocket) in the upper-right to roll the ship out to the launchpad. It might take a second to load; that's normal, it's just prepping all the textures and the world environment.

Now, given that you're teaching about solar sails, you should know they don't work in an atmosphere$^\text{citation needed}$, and we didn't exactly build a launch vehicle (nor do I expect you to build a fully-functional orbital launcher on your first try in KSP), so press Alt-F12 (or Mac/Linux equivalent) to open the cheat menu. You can click on Cheats, Set Orbit, and then hit the button to teleport your ship into the selected orbit of the body.

After a second of loading, it'll look like this, but less cool because I have a lot of fun graphics mods installed:

Right-click and drag to rotate the camera and take in the beauty of space, and use the scroll wheel to zoom in/out. Now, to deploy the solar sail, right click on the sail to bring up its menu. It'll look something like this:

To deploy it, press "Deploy Sail" at the bottom.


You can use WASD to spin the ship around (not forever because reaction wheels need power, but for long enough.) Note that pretty much as soon as deployment finishes, your velocity will start changing:

In this shot, the camera auto-rotated so that the ground is "down" because wow, I'm suddenly on a suborbital trajectory! As it turns out the batteries and probe core and solar sail are actually really quite light, and the solar sail we just deployed is quite large. If you set your direction prograde, which is the little circle-with-three-lines down at the navball, you'll very quickly start accelerating away from the sun/forward through your orbit, at sort of an unbelievable speed. This particular sail happens to be very efficient; quickly, unless you do something about it, you'll find that your sail melts and explodes, and then you're left with this:


moving at well over 5 km/s. (The Kerbol system is ~1/12th scale, so orbital velocity in low Kerbin orbit is ~2.2 km/s.)
Of course, the sail I happened to pick in that case was the most efficient one available. The gold one, for example, weighs less but is also less efficient, if I'm not mistaken. If you hit Escape, Revert Flight, Revert to Build, you can ignore all the mistakes you just made and go back to the VAB to fix them :)
That's the 20,000ft view of it. I highly recommend KSP for all things space simulation. If you want more realism - like the real Solar System instead of the Kerbol System - you can also play with the Real Solar System (RSS) mod. RSS adds in a to-scale replica of the Solar System, complete with accurate launch sites on Earth and everything. It has some dependencies that come with it but it's fundamentally the same game.
If you want to see the solar sail's motion over time, you can also use M to look at the map and use ,/. to slow down/speed up time to watch the orbit change in real time. Solar sails are finicky - one of the main issues with them is that trading off heating and acceleration can be inconvenient. ACS3 is still an active mission. KSP is a great way to model it in the meantime, though.
